# Mock Multiple Static Methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have a class like which makes two different static function calls one of which is some Util function while the other is local to the class, like this:

```
public class A {
    .
    .
    public static myfunc1() {
        obj1 = myfunc(param);
        .
        .
        Obj obj = Util.getObj(param);
        .
        .
    }

    static obj1 myfunc(param) {
        ..
    }
}
```

I want to write unit test for this class which looks something like this:

```
public class Atest {
    .
    .
    public void testMyfunc1() {
        .
        .
        A a = new A();
        A spyA = spy(a);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(mockObj).when(spyA).myfunc(mockParam);
        .
        .
    }
    .
    .
}
```

But it is giving me UnfinishedStubbingException.

I also tried doing like this:

```
PowerMockito.when(spyA.myfunc(mockParam)).thenReturn(mockObj);
```

But it does not override the function.

*And secondly, I need to know that how can I override the Util.getObj() function.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I came to know that PowerMock provides a module called easymock wherein there is method called `mockStaticPartial` which mocks specific static functions in a class. As for Utils.getObj() method, similar thing can be done. So, my test class now looks like something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class, Utils.class})
public class Atest {
    .
    .
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        .
        .
        mockStaticPartial(A.class, "myfunc");
        mockStatic(Utils.class);
        .
        .
    }

    public void testMyfunc1() {
        .
        .
        PowerMockito.when(A.mufync()).thenReturn(mockObj1);
        PowerMockito.when(Utils.getObj(mockParam)).thenReturn(mockObj);
        .
        .
        //More testing logic goes here
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spies are for mocking class instances, but static methods are class level. You should use [`PowerMockito.mockStatic`](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) or [`PowerMockito.spy`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.7/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#spy%28java.lang.Class%29).

However, the best approach - refactor the code and get rid of statics.

Comment: I've tried using `PowerMockito.mockStatic` but it overrides all the functions in my class (say class A) and hence does not test the method (myfunc1) in my class. Please see the edit to the question.

Comment: Use PowerMockito.spy then